# Remove duplication from big table with laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table with 5 millions records and it has duplicated rows
I want to remove the duplication.
This is my code

```php
$userRoles = Model::groupBy('phone','user_id','name')->get();
$userRolesId = array_column($userRoles ->toArray(), 'id');
Model::whereNotIn('id', $userRolesId )->delete();
```

URL exists but it returns an error after five minutes of loading. And when I tried it for a small table it works perfectly.

Comment: Is the route for the controller function defined? Did you clear the route cache?

Comment: 404 has nothing to do with the code! [Its a page not found error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

Comment: First of all, that means that it is not really a 404 error, but a timeout error. Running a script that runs 5 minutes or more? then it looks normal to me that it gets a timeout error. if you want to remove duplicates, maybe its better to use a console command, and split it in multiple runs that delete a limited amount of duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 that mean you call route not exist in your application ,

If the incoming request does not match the route pattern constraints, a 404 HTTP response will be returned.
no problem in your code :-

```
$userRoles = Model::groupBy('phone','user_id','name')->get();
$userRolesId = array_column($userRoles ->toArray(), 'id');
Model::whereNotIn('id', $userRolesId )->delete();
```

Comment: Url is exist It returns that error after five minutes of loading and I tried it for small table it works perfect

Comment: thats mean your scrip reach the max time execution , 
$start = microtime(true);
$userRoles = Model::groupBy('phone','user_id','name')->get();
$userRolesId = array_column($userRoles ->toArray(), 'id');
dd( microtime(true) - $start);

then told use the result

Comment: you can increase the execution time in phpini , or you can use lazy collection will help you working with large data ( https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#lazy-collections ) 
or you can use job batching ( https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-batching )

Comment: result is 291.67524313927

Comment: my execration time is 300

Comment: ok its .3 second not much compare with your data , 
you can use lazy collelction it save time and memory like this  :-

LazyCollection::make(function () {
   $userRoles = Model::groupBy('phone','user_id','name')->get();
   $userRolesId = array_column($userRoles ->toArray(), 'id');
   $data = Model::whereNotIn('id', $userRolesId );

   foreach($items as $item){
       yield $item;
}

   }
})
->each(function ($item) {
   dd($item); // you can do $item->delete()
});


i use lazy collection in larage data , if data more than 5 million i use job and job batching

Comment: LazyCollection works with at least Laravel 6 but project version is 5.8

Comment: you can do that by using laravel job , but you need to make chuncs from Model::whereNotIn('id', $userRolesId ) with size 10000 for example , then run your job

Comment: try this query :- 
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("

    DELETE t1 FROM your_table AS t1 INNER JOIN your_table AS t2   
    WHERE t1.id < t1.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.phone = t2.phone AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id;  

'") );

Comment: This query has sql error I tested it in phpmyadmin and in php code

Comment: can you show the error to us ?

Comment: query DB::select( DB::raw(" DELETE t1 FROM `user_phone_news` AS t1 INNER JOIN `user_phone_news` AS t2 WHERE t1.id < t1.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.phone = t2.phone AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id; '") );
error :  Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

Comment: try this you have mistake in your condation and in single quotes at the end of the query try this :-   " DELETE t1 FROM user_phone_news AS t1 INNER JOIN user_phone_news AS t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.phone = t2.phone AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id "